# Read deserialized data using RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

Im using RestSharp to deserialize a Json file:
i created the classs

```
public class ListaUsuario
{
    public List<Usuario>usuarios { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public long username { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public string inf_huella { get; set; }
    public string inf_qr { get; set; }
}
```

And im using the code:

```
var request1 = new RestSharp.RestRequest("api/users?token=" + JSONObj["token"], RestSharp.Method.GET);
request1.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
request1.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
var response2 = client.Execute(request1);
var  Lista = deserial1.Deserialize<List<Usuario>>(response2)
```

To deserialize the data. But i want to know. How i can access to "Lista" and read the information.

Comment: It's not perfectly clear what you mean... Lista is a collection (list in this case) of objects which type is Usuario... You can access it as every regular list

Comment: Are you sure your deserialization is right? I'd say the statement should be `var Lista = deserial1.Deserialize<ListaUsuario>(response2);`